# failed AMD Radeon 5XXX graphic card

Tags: windows, graphics-card, amd-radeon

At the beginning..,I installed windows 8 with defined graphics card amd successfully
After several days, and after running the store and download some software and games, began to show lines on the screen and then stopped work windows and show physical error 'video_tdr_failure'

After reboot!, remained lines appear even the bios! and when startup! as this photo
[image: when startup windows]

I installed ubuntu and windows 7 for experimentation!, And after the completion of the installation of windows 7 back screen function normally! (Without graphics card driver), and when install driver of graphics card or run some programs, back to show the lines on the screen (without showing physical error)!

When restore the system before installing driver, goes back to work as normal! And so on ..etc :(

These are some of the pictures show the problem ...
[image]

[image]

I just need to know that the problem from the driver of software or Hardware problem and needed to switch the entire card!? :(
And How do I test the graphics card to make sure of it!?

Thank you for your answer .. :)

Comment: You have a hardware failure.

Comment: I have to replace it? or repaired it?

Comment: You won't be able repair a failure with a graphics card....

Comment: Just a little extra insight here; `video_tdr_error` stands for `Timeout Detection and Recovery`. It means something took far too long to finish on the GPU, and Windows is resetting the GPU driver. In the past (before this feature was added to Windows Vista), when an event like that occurred the system would basically deadlock and you would have to reboot. Moreover, the ***error*** part means WIndows was unable to reset the driver. This looks like a problem with your GPU's memory, and unfortunately that is not something that can be serviced - you are going to have to buy a new card :-\